# How's the performance with '.has' and without '.has' when creating element for Set data structure?

Tags: javascript, performance, set

I have this two functions which does the same thing, to insert only unique element into a set. Just wondering, how is the performance difference is it checks the element before insert verses without?

```
function removeAllDup(n) {
    // Set (ES6) is a collection for unique values.
    let seen = new Set;

    n.forEach(item => seen.add(item));

    return seen;
}

function removeAllDup2(n) {
    // Set (ES6) is a collection for unique values.
    let seen = new Set;

    n.forEach(element => {
        // if element does not exist in the set, add the element.
        if (!seen.has(element)) {
            seen.add(element);
        }
    })

    return seen;
}
```

Comment: Why is additional `seen.has` step required considering `Set` already takes care of that automatically?

Comment: i know there is this additional .has step for the same output. that's why i wish to know if adding .has does improve or decrease the insertion performance ?

Comment: ... Can't you check for yourself?

Comment: Well, `Set` has no idea you have performed the `has` check manually. So it's going to check for itself anyway. So, no. `has` doesn't improve anything. Create snippets on [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/) and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set will check the new value by itself, the 'has' check isn't needed.